# touch response event ios4

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, touch, first-responder

I added a ViewController to an app for ad banner support. The app was based on a UINavigationController so I added the ViewController as a subview to the UINavigationController. Now the area of the ad banner does not recognize when it is touched to open the ad in safari. I have tried to make the ViewController becomeFirstResponder but that doesn't work. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you say you added it as a subview, but I hope you mean you pushed it with

`- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

Your view controller can respond to events because it is a UIResponder. UIView and therefore most visual controls like UIButton, UISlider etc. inherit from UIResponder also - but they implement specific actions based on user interaction.

If you really want to intercept events in a UIViewController you will need to handle touchesBegan/Moved/Ended events. More likely you have at least a UIWebView or UIImageView in the view controller if it is displaying something you want to click on.

If UIWebView you'll need a UIWebViewDelegate implementing

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

will let you know what links are being opened.

If a UIImageView you will also need to set the property `userInteractionEnabled` before you see any touch events.

If you're dealing with iAd's AdBannerView class, that inherits from UIView also, so comments for UIImageView apply. HOWEVER ADBannerViewDelegate is a requirement for built-in interaction support - just like UIWebViewDelegate, you must implement a permission/notification function,

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
```